# Convert array of type either float or strings to int type in Julia (Replicating int() from Python)

Tags: string, type-conversion, integer, julia

I would like to replicate the functionality of python function `int()` which can convert either `string` or `float` to a `int` type with base of 10.

Reference: https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_int.asp

I have developed a small code to perform this execution:

```
a = "5.9"
print("Type of a = ", typeof(a))
if typeof(a) == String
    x1 = reinterpret(Int64, a)  # 1st attempt
    x1 = parse(Int, a)          # 2nd attempt
else 
    x1 = floor(Int64, a) 
end
print("\nx1 = $x1", ",\t","type of x1 = ", typeof(x1))
```

In the above code, I have shown the functions to convert the string to `int` type but neither works.

Please do suggest a solution which can convert the `string` to `int` and also for any recommendation to optimize the above code?

Thanks!

Comment: As `a = "5.9"` is not of type Int, you should try parsing it to eg. Float64 first and then apply an appropriate rounding function like this: `Int(round(parse(Float64, "5.9")))`.

Comment: In python (see your reference link) 'int' does not work for "5.9" and gives the following error. ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '5.9'

Comment: @mapi1 thanks for the suggestion, it works now!!! highly appreciate it !!

Comment: @callmeSteve Yeah agree, the `int` in python cannot convert **float-type string** it only works for **int-type string** i.e `int('10')`.

Answer (score 5):

This is a good example to play with multiple dispatch. Instead of comparing type (btw, it's better to write `a isa String` instead of `typeof(a) == String`), you can define multiple functions with different behavior.

```
myparse(x::Nothing) = nothing
myparse(x::Integer) = x
myparse(x::Real) = Int(round(x))
myparse(x::AbstractString) = myparse(tryparse(Float64, x))
```

and this is how it looks in action

```
julia> myparse(1)
1

julia> myparse(1.0)
1

julia> myparse(1.1)
1

julia> myparse("12.3")
12

julia> myparse("asdsad")
```

In last case it can't parse string, so it just return `nothing`.

Comment: Could use `round(Int, x)`

Comment: @DNF definitely he should use that!

Comment: @DNF thanks for the suggestion, but directly using `round()` returns the nearest integer for example -> `round(Int, 5.3)` = 5` while `round(Int, 5.7) = 6` . What I wanted was it to just return the real integer irrespective of it decimal value.

Comment: @AndrejOskin Thanks for the response, I didn't think of this approach. Amazing suggestion !!!! I shall try to use this approach. Highly appreciate it !

Comment: @PrzemyslawSzufel thanks for the reply, I tried using the `round()` function but due to the reasons mentioned in the reply to @DNF I couldn't proceed with the function. But if there is work around please do share, highly appreciate it !!

Comment: I added an answer for you

Answer (score 3):

Shorter form:

```
myparse(x::Real) = trunc(Int, x)
myparse(::Nothing) = nothing
myparse(x::AbstractString) = myparse(tryparse(Float64, x))
```

`trunc` drops the floating point and only integer part is left, e.g.:

```
julia> myparse("-4.7")
-4
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, this is amazing, I highly appreciate it !!